# How to keep a function continuously activated

Tags: c#, function, winforms

I am using C# Windows Form to create an interface with another software.

1. My software has different inputs and outputs (boolean) called DI1 DI2 DO1 DO2.
2. On my C# app I have a function which allows the synchronization :

```
public void synchro() 
{
   if (switchbutton1.Checked)
      DI1 = true;
   else 
      DI1 = false;

   if (switchbutton1.Checked)
      DI2 = true;
   else 
      DI2 = false;

   if (D01 == true)
      led.Value = true; // turn on a led
   else 
      DI1 = false;

   if (D02 == true)
      led.Value = true; // turn on a led
   else 
      DI2 = false;
}
```

I'm beginning in C# and I want to know where I can put my function to keep it continuously synchronized.
Except timers because it blinks my leds even when they are turned off.

Comment: Call synchro from switchbutton1.CheckedChanged Event.

Comment: What do you mean with "keep it continuously synchronized"? Are the `D...` variables changed by something else..?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. It is not really clear what you mean by synchronisation. If you have checkboxes, then you can use the [CheckedChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event to react to the user input and set the appropriate signals

Comment: No, I can't because if my output D01 or D02 is true on my software my led won't turn on because the switchbutton1.CheckedChanged won't be activated.

Comment: @SanMiguel Then you'll need to call this function whenever you change D01 or D02 somewhere.

Comment: "because if my output D01 or D02 is true on my software" how can this happen? please show us the code

Comment: If I activate my switch on C# my inputs on my soft = 1, if my soft's outputs changed I want my leds to turn on or off on my app.

Comment: How does "your soft" change `DO1` and `DO2` in your C# app?

Comment: It is an integrated automation software with program blocks. With another class on C# I make the link between the soft and my app. If I change something on any of the two my Outputs or Inputs should follow but I want it to continuously synchronize for my leds. I don't want to use an event because my outputs can blink( 0 1 0 1 0 1) and the led won't if it is not synchronized continuously.

Comment: What integrated automation software? It probably has an event handler for things like this. _Please_ show how the rest is hooked up here!

Comment: Is `D01` a property or a field? Are you able to modify its code?

Comment: I used a timer before because it never stops until you decide to, but visually it has a failure that's why I'm searching for something else.

Comment: Yes I can modify but I don't want It's not my part, it is LAD programming with a specific code which allows my outputs to be 1 or 0. I don't know if it has event handler. I just want to put my C# function in a continuous stuff like timer. :/

Comment: I have tried something like `Thread sync = new Thread(() => synchro());`
But it said my leds are used in another thread than the one in which they are created

Comment: What exactly does _visually it has a failure_ mean?

Comment: The leds are blinking, i mean they are visible and invisible really quickly. It is like a refresh of my leds

Comment: I don't want my leds to refresh every tick of my timer, only when the value changes

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use this function continuously then that would be better if your Timer with interval as per your requirements. Its will call continuously and your functions will call every time.

Comment: OP explicitly says "except timers".

Comment: @AKX depends upon functionality mentioned in function. How much time required to complete this functionality , other wise if you provide less time than required time to  complete execute then will not get output properly.

Comment: Please see OP's post and comments as to why a timer is not suitable for this situation.

Comment: I used a timer before because it never stops until you decide to, but visually it has a failure that's why I'm searching for something else. It blinks my leds even when they are turned off like they are always refreshing

Comment: @SanMiguel as per your need kindly do enable = true & enable = false in timer.

Comment: don't want to use timer :/

Answer (score 0):

You should separate out the code that accesses the checkbox control, since it has thread affinity. I can't see any reason not to put it in an  event handler.

As for the bit about reading the `D0#` registers, you can run that in an infinite loop, and execute it in an asynchronous task that you cancel and await when you unload the form.

```
Task _syncTask;
CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

public void switchbutton1_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var flag = switchbutton1.Checked;
    DI1 = flag;
    DI2 = flag;
}

public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _syncTask = Sync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}

public async void Form_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    await _syncTask;
}


async Task Sync(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (D01 == true)
            led.Value = true; // turn on a led
        else 
            DI1 = false;
        if (D02 == true)
            led.Value = true; // turn on a led
        else 
            DI2 = false;
        await Task.Delay(10, token);  //Refresh 100 times per second
    }
}
```

Comment: But this, again, is essentially a Timer, which OP doesn't want.